# First and last days of month given a specific day of that month - shell

Tags: shell, date

I can get the first and last days of the current month

```
#first
date -d "-0 month -$(($(date +%d)-1)) days" +%Y%m%d
#last
date -d "-$(date +%d) days +1 month" +%Y%m%d
```

Now, if I'm accepting a particular day of the month in `YYYYMMDD` format as an argument like `indate="$1"`, how can I use this to get the first and last dates for that corresponding month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
indate='20160215'

# first day of given month
date -d "$indate -${indate:6} days +1 day" +%Y%m%d
20160201

# last day of given month
date -d "$indate +1 month -${indate:6} days" +%Y%m%d
20160229
```

Comment: Worked like a charm... Thanks!